# ubuntu system crontab works, but root crontab does not

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I am having a strange problem about ubuntu crontab here.

If I add the following line to system crontab(/etc/crontab), it works well

```
*/1 * * * * root /bin/date >> /root/text
```

but if I edit root crontab by using `crontab -e` with root user, and add

```
*/1 * * * * /bin/date >> /root/text
```

it does not work at all.

Can you please help me on this?

Thank you

### update and answer

I got my answer after searching server fault, the reason is explained in [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/72237/user-cron-jobs-are-not-running-but-system-jobs-are).

The reason is that crontab file **need a newline** in the end, otherwise it will not work.

Comment: Have you used `sudo crontab -e' ? To create crontab for root you may need `sudo crontab -eu root'

Comment: Probably belongs on serverfault

Comment: I did not use sudo. I actually logged in as root directly

Comment: Btw can you tell the difference between `*/1` and solely `*` in the first column?

Answer (score 2):

OP found the solution:

> I got my answer after searching server fault, the reason is explained in [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/72237/user-cron-jobs-are-not-running-but-system-jobs-are).
>
> The reason is that crontab file **need a newline** in the end, otherwise it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You may can check if you have `/etc/cron.allow` and/or `/etc/cron.deny` files and contents of these files. Here you have excerpt from man page `crontab(1)`:

> If the `/etc/cron.allow` file exists, then you must be listed therein in order to be allowed to use this command.  If  the  `/etc/cron.allow`  file  does  not  exist  but  the `/etc/cron.deny`  file  does exist, then you must not be listed in the `/etc/cron.deny` file in order to use this command.  If neither of these files exists, then depending on site-dependent configuration parameters, only the super user will be allowed to use this command, or all users will be able to use this command. For standard  Debian  systems, all users may use this command.

Comment: thank you for answering. I just checked whether cron.allow or cron.deny exists in /etc. But I found neither of them there.
Is there any other reason why I can not get root crontab working?

Comment: According to docs it should work for root user and as I see you found your answer :).

 But you can always put empty `cron.deny` file for allow all users to access to the cron or put only allowed users in cron.allow file. I think it will more precise that doesn't have any of these files (in that case the behavior is not consistent between different systems) .

Comment: AFAIK cron.deny and cron.allow do not exist by default in debian based distros. Only centos redhat ship them by default.